# PHP Else-if Statement For Routing to different page

Tags: php

In this code if `$row['division']` is `Leech` it shows the link of related page.  When `$row['division']` is `DME` it's showing blank space and even it's not showing the last part of `else statement`.

```
<td>
    <a rel="facebox"  
    <?php if ($row['division']=="Leech") { ?>
        href="viewevaldme.php?evaid=<?php echo $row['evaid']; ?>" >  
    <?php } elseif ($row['division']=="DME") { ?>
        href="vieweval.php?evaid=<?php echo $row['evaid']; ?> " 
    <?php } else { echo "Wrong Division Selected"; } ?>
        Click Here 
    </a> 
</td>
```

Comment: you have closed the tag `<a>` in if condition ,please remove the `>` after the `href` in if condition i.e. it should be like `<a rel="facebox"  
     <?php if ($row['division']=="Leech") { ?> href="viewevaldme.php?evaid=<?php echo $row['evaid']; ?> "   
  <?php } elseif ($row['division']=="DME") { ?>href="vieweval.php?evaid=<?php echo $row['evaid']; ?> " 
  <?php } else { echo "Wrong Division Selected"; } ?> > Click Here 
</a> `

Comment: It seems that you already closed the opening `<a>` tag in the `if statement` . So if it reaches the other condition, your `href` will be outside the `<a>` tag. One more thing. it would be better if you get the value of `href` first before echoing it inside `<a>`, so that it is cleaner

Answer (score 3):

**Try This :**

```
    <td>
     <?php 
        if ($row['division'] == "Leech") {
            echo '<a rel="facebox" href="viewevaldme.php?evaid='.$row['evaid'].'">Click Here</a>';
        } elseif($row['division'] =="DME") {
            echo '<a rel="facebox" href="vieweval.php?evaid='.$row['evaid'].'">Click Here</a> ';
        } else {
            echo 'Wrong Division Selected';
        }
     ?>           
    </td>
```

Comment: Love to see a quick response from all friends ... Now it's working what i want ...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<td>
        <?php
        if ($row['division'] === "Leech") {
            print '<a rel="facebox" href="viewevaldme.php?evaid='.$row['evaid'].'">Click Here</a>';
        } elseif($row['division']==="DME") {
            print '<a rel="facebox" href="vieweval.php?evaid='.$row['evaid'].'">Click Here</a> ';
        } else {
            print 'Wrong Division Selected';
        }
        ?>
</td>
```